# Make derived classes in homogeneous container interect differently with each other

Tags: c++, polymorphism, dynamic-cast

I encountered an unexpected problem while programming the Sokoban game when I had to deal with polymorphism.
Here is my simplified class hierarchy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void onContact(GameObject* otherObject)
    {
        cout << "object met object" << endl;
    }
};

class Crate;
class Wall;
class Hero;

class Crate: public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void onContact(Wall* w)
    {
        cout << "crate met wall" << endl;
    }
    virtual void onContact(Hero* h)
    {
        cout << "crate met hero" << endl;
    }
};

class Wall: public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void onContact(Crate* c)
    {
        cout << "wall met crate" << endl;
    }
    virtual void onContact(Hero* h)
    {
        cout << "wall met hero" << endl;
    }
};


class Hero: public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void onContact(Crate* crate)
    {
        cout << "hero met crate" << endl;
    }
    virtual void onContact(Wall* w)
    {
        cout << "hero met wall" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    //Works
    auto hero = unique_ptr<Hero>(new Hero());
    auto crate = unique_ptr<Crate>(new Crate());
    auto wall = unique_ptr<Wall>(new Wall());

    hero->onContact(crate.get()); // "hero met crate"
    hero->onContact(wall.get()); // "hero met wall"
    crate->onContact(wall.get()); // "crate met wall"
    wall->onContact(crate.get()); // "wall met crate"

    cout << endl;

    //Problem: in the program the game objects are stored in a vector (homogeneous container)
    vector<unique_ptr<GameObject>> gameObjects;
    gameObjects.push_back(move(hero));
    gameObjects.push_back(move(crate));
    gameObjects.push_back(move(wall));

    /* 
    "object met object".
    Should be "hero met crate".
    That's because all objects in vector are GameObject.
    */
    gameObjects[0]->onContact(gameObjects[1].get());

    /* "object met object", should be "wall met crate" */
    gameObjects[2]->onContact(gameObjects[1].get());

    return 0;
}
```

So here's my question/problem: as most(all?) stl containers are homogeneous, all derived objects are stored as base objects (in my case GameObject), thus hindering a proper polymorphism depending on the type of the argument in the method onContact.

How to climb back to the original type, without dynamic casting (and checking what worked) everything and everywhere? 
Is there a flaw in the class design?

Thank you for your help.

TL;DR: How to apply elegantly polymorphism in an homogeneous collection of derived objects interacting differently with each other?

Gist: https://gist.github.com/gaultier/e437877395b5831a0623

Comment: Please post something that's free of random errors. I see numerous errors in this code that has nothing to do with what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of double-dispatch mechanism. One possibility would be to use the visitor pattern to dispatch your collider on the runtime type of both objects.

Put default behaviour into your base class:

```
class GameObject
{
    public:
  virtual void contactHandlerDefault(GameObject* otherObject)
  {
    cout << "met an other object";
  }

  virtual void contactHandlerCrate(Crate* o);
  virtual void contactHandlerWall(Wall* o);
  virtual void contactHandlerHero(Hero* o);

  virtual void onContact(GameObject* otherObject)
  {
    otherObject->contactHandlerDefault(this);
  }
};
```

Then for each of your derived classes, override any collision handler you want, then make them cast their `this` pointer to the correct static type and forward themselves to the right handler in the collided object:

```
class Hero: public GameObject
{
public:
  virtual void onContact(GameObject* otherObject) override
  {
    otherObject->contactHandlerHero(static_cast<Hero*>(this));
  }

  virtual void contactHandlerDefault(GameObject* obj) override
  {
    cout << "do nothing, I can't go through";
  }

  virtual void contactHandlerCrate(Crate* crate) override
  {
    cout << "pushing the crate";
  }
};
```

Then make the base class handlers forward to the default one (you could do this with overloading, which would mean you wouldn't need to do this, but this way you get a compilation error if you add a new class and don't add the handlers to it):

```
void GameObject::contactHandlerCrate(Crate* o)
{
  contactHandlerDefault(o);
}
//...
```

Now calling `gameObjects[1]->onContact(gameObjects[0]);` outputs `pushing the crate`. Note that this method means that you need to reverse your calls, so instead of calling `hero->onContact(crate)`, you call `crate->onContact(hero)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TartanLlama, I implemented it right.
I also learned that it is called double dispatch: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

Only thing to care of is the reverse order:

> Note that this method means that you need to reverse your calls, so instead of calling hero->onContact(crate), you call crate->onContact(hero).

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Crate;
class Wall;
class Hero;

class GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void onContact(GameObject* o)
    {
        o->onContactHandler(this);
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(GameObject* o)
    {
        cout << "object met object" << endl;
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(Hero* h)
    {
        cout << "object met hero" << endl;
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(Wall* w)
    {
        cout << "object met wall" << endl;
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(Crate* c)
    {
        cout << "object met crate" << endl;
    }
};

class Crate: public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void onContact(GameObject* o) override
    {
        o->onContactHandler(static_cast<Crate*>(this));
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(Wall* w) override
    {
        cout << "crate met wall" << endl;
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(Hero* h) override
    {
        cout << "crate met hero" << endl;
    }
};

class Wall: public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void onContact(GameObject* o) override
    {
        o->onContactHandler(static_cast<Wall*>(this));
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(Crate* c) override
    {
        cout << "wall met crate" << endl;
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(Hero* h) override
    {
        cout << "wall met hero" << endl;
    }
};


class Hero: public GameObject
{
public:
    virtual void onContact(GameObject* o) override
    {
        o->onContactHandler(static_cast<Hero*>(this));
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(Crate* c) override
    {
       cout << "hero met crate" << endl;
    }
    virtual void onContactHandler(Wall* w) override
    {
        cout << "hero met wall" << endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
    auto hero = unique_ptr<Hero>(new Hero());
    auto crate = unique_ptr<Crate>(new Crate());
    auto wall = unique_ptr<Wall>(new Wall());

    hero->onContact(crate.get()); // "crate met hero"
    hero->onContact(wall.get()); // "wall met hero"
    crate->onContact(wall.get()); // "wall met crate"
    wall->onContact(crate.get()); // "crate met wall"

    cout << endl;

    vector<unique_ptr<GameObject>> gameObjects;
    gameObjects.push_back(move(hero));
    gameObjects.push_back(move(crate));
    gameObjects.push_back(move(wall));

    gameObjects[0]->onContact(gameObjects[1].get()); //crate met hero
    gameObjects[2]->onContact(gameObjects[1].get()); //crate met wall

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Gist: https://gist.github.com/gaultier/e437877395b5831a0623 (second file)